# Открыть файл c помощью phonegap

Tags: phonegap, файлы, javascript

Делал все по инструкции [отсюда](https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener)

Но файл все равно не открывается. 
[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206288/phonegap-opening-a-pdf-error-document-could-not-be-opened) тот же вопрос, но не решает моей проблемы.

Может я чего-то упустил?

В config.xml вставил:

```
 <plugins>
 <plugin name="FileOpener" value="com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener.FileOpener"/>
 </plugins>
```

Создал новую папку \src\com\phonegap\plugins\fileopener и поместил туда FileOpener.java

в html добавил строки

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fileopener.js"></script>
```

Пытаюсь запустить, нажимаю на ссылку, никакой реакции.

```
 <a href="#"  onclick="window.plugins.fileOpener.open('file:///sdcard/Download/1.jpg');">open</a>
```

Comment: Цитата:  
  
In your `res/xml/plugins.xml` file add the following line:  

    <plugin name="FileOpener" value="com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener.FileOpener"/>

В инструкции так написано.

Comment: пути -- точно правильные?.. линукс он зело резко реагирует на большие/малые буквы..